# click on a button and inside a button to raise another button to be clicked with code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

For example I have 2 buttons:

```
<asp:button id="button1" onClick="Button1_click" runat="server"/>
<asp:button id="button2" runat="server"/>

Button1_click(sender, args)
{
   //how to call button 2 to be clicked?
}
```

How could I write code behind to fire the button2 to be clicked?

Comment: what do you want to happen with button 2 is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure y u would want to do this but here it goes

```
<asp:button id="button1" onClick="Button1_click" runat="server"/>
<asp:button id="button2" runat="server"/>

Button1_click(sender, args)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "click", "var btn=document.getElementById('button2');btn.click();", true);
}
```

Comment: Hi,

In some cases, I would like to do so for my own purpose.

Thanks for your answer.

But the problem is that if I place two buttons inside of an updatepanel then ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript will not work. If I use endRequest then it will raise every time. I just want to fire the event when I want.

Comment: @JoseyXHN - I am not sure what you are trying to acheive, if you explain it further then probably i can help you out. also your question doesn't say anything about update panels.

Comment: thanks for your kind comment.

Actually, what I want to achieve is:

Adding a button inside an UpdatePanel, checking in code-behind of this button event. In case needed, I will need to call a method from javascript. I could do this by adding EndRequest after postback but EndRequest will raise any time even I dont call it. This is what I have got until now.

Any advice please?